# Hyper-Threading In The Host

Tags: windows, virtualization, vmware-vsphere

If I only have access to the virtual machine and not the host itself, is it possible to know for sure if the host computer is using hyper-threading or not? If it is, how can I do this for a Windows VM?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not (easily) possible. The guest never knows how it's process threads are executed - that's why we have hypervisors in the first place.